# Temporal Difference (Reinforcement Learning) by h2o

Tags: h2o

I am wondering to know if h2o is capable of implementing Temporal Difference (reinforcement learning)?

I know TensorFlow has the capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O's list of available algorithms can be found [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science.html). The short answer to your question is no. Details on the Deep Learning algorithm that is available [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html) and I will repost for your convenience:

H2O-3's Deep Learning algorithm is based on a multi-layer feedforward artificial neural network that is trained with stochastic gradient descent using back-propagation. The network can contain a large number of hidden layers consisting of neurons with tanh, rectifier, and maxout activation functions. Advanced features such as adaptive learning rate, rate annealing, momentum training, dropout, L1 or L2 regularization, checkpointing, and grid search enable high predictive accuracy. Each compute node trains a copy of the global model parameters on its local data with multi-threading (asynchronously) and contributes periodically to the global model via model averaging across the network.

A feedforward artificial neural network (ANN) model, also known as deep neural network (DNN) or multi-layer perceptron (MLP), is the most common type of Deep Neural Network and the only type that is supported natively in H2O-3. Several other types of DNNs are popular as well, such as Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) and Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs). MLPs work well on transactional (tabular) data; however if you have image data, then CNNs are a great choice. If you have sequential data (e.g. text, audio, time-series), then RNNs are a good choice.